# Importing Templates in Meteor During Routing with Iron Router

Tags: templates, meteor, iron-router

One of the benefits to Meteor is that you only need to load content when it needs to be rendered, e.g. if you have a template file in /imports/ui/client it is not loaded unless you import it somewhere. However, when using Iron Router I've been unable to determine how I should include a template only when it needs to be rendered via the appropriate route. One approach I've tried is declaring the import in the route function:

```
Router.route('/', function () {
  import '/imports/ui/client/home.js';
  this.render('home');
});
```

This succeeds in loading the template file, though I've not seen any examples in the Iron Router documentation doing it this way and I've had some JavaScript issues that I didn't have previously, as such I'm doubtful this is the right/best approach.

When using Meteor with Iron Router what is the best way to include templates only when they're needed?

Comment: One of the JavaScript issues I alluded to above is that if in my home.js file from the above example contains an import statement with the HTML template, and then some JavaScript, the JavaScript renders before the HTML template is loaded. The HTML template needs to render first.

Answer (score 0):

```
import '/imports/ui/client/home.js';

Router.route('/', function () {

  this.render('home');
});
```

This is the 'standard' way as mentioned in most of the [examples](https://themeteorchef.com/snippets/understanding-the-imports-directory/), though I see no harm in your way.

Comment: Thanks. However, I don't see how this works. Assuming I define this route in the routes.js file under a startup or root folder the template contained in home.js will always be loaded in the app, rather than only when the home page is rendered.

Comment: can you please share a repo or the boiler plate?

Answer (score 0):

i do it like this...

```
Router.route('/join', {
  name: 'join',
  onBeforeAction: function() {
    import '../../ui/pages/join/join.js';
    this.next();
  }
});
```